# Batch Script to copy contents of one folder to the other under C:\Program Files (x86) location. Not working - Acess Denied Error

Tags: batch-file, runas

I have written simple batch script, which copies contents of one folder to the other. I have already logged into the machine as Admin. I am working on windows-7 machine.

Folder 1 and Folder 2

Location of folders :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder1  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder2
```

If i am running my script by double clicking it, i am getting Access Denied. If I right click on file "Run as Administrators" it correctly copies.

Expected Behavior: 
On directly double clicking the batch script it should copy the file.As i am already logged in as Admin.

Waiting for valuable feedback, from fellow coder's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following script, helps to run your batch file as "Run As Admin".

```
@echo off
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload
    echo %~nx0: running payload with parameters:
    echo %*
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    echo ADM is launching. DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW.
    cd /d %2
    shift
    shift
    echo Name of the batch file which you want to run as admin
    CopyFiles.bat 
goto :eof

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your users group does not have Read and Execute permissions to the command processor,

please have a look at the solution described here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/867466

Comment: Thanks..But i am already login as Admin. Why should i "Run As Administrator"

Comment: While you are logged as admin, the programs you execute do not run with the fullest permissions. This is a security measure to avoid risks as most people run by default with Administartor account,

Comment: So what is the solution for it. Becuase i see aready read and execute permisiion on the batch script

Comment: UAC is not allowing your script to access the Program Files directory, you need to run your batch file as administrator for this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(v=ws.10).aspx   
you can disable UAC if this a constant burden, but I wouldn't advise it: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Thanks Alex and SAIndia.